# How to configure an App Service Managed Certificate for an Azure Function in an Azure Resource Manager Template?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-resource-manager

I have an ARM template in which I am configuring a Function App.

Here is a sample of my ARM template that deals with the Function App:

```
{
    "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
    "name": "MyAzureFunctionName",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "kind": "functionapp",
    "dependsOn": [
         "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('nameWithDashes'))]",
         "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageName'))]"
    ],
    "properties": {
         "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', 'MyAzureFunctionName')]",
         "httpsOnly": true,
         "siteConfig": {
             "appSettings": [
                 {
                     ...
                 }]
         }
     }
}
```

I have successfully configured a custom domain 'mydomain.ca' in my Function App using the following configuration:

```
{
    "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/hostNameBindings",
    "name": "[concat('MyFunctionApp', '/', 'mydomain.ca')]",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "scale": null,
    "properties": {
    },
    "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('nameWithDashes'))]"
    ]
}
```

The next step in securing my Function App is to bind the custom domain to an SSL certificate. I am trying to find a way to use the App Service Managed Certificate so that Azure will create and manage the certificate itself (See the option `Create App Service Managed Certificate` below).

[image: App Service Managed Certificate]

**Question**

How can I configure an App Service Managed Certificate for the custom domain of my Function App in an Azure Resource Manager Template?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://dotnetdevlife.wordpress.com/2019/11/12/arm-app-service-managed-certificate/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment [Alex made](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/certificates#certificateproperties-object) helped a lot ; it had all the important pieces. However I was not able to make it work using the linked template.

Instead of using a linked template, I fell back to using [a nested template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/linked-templates#nested-template) and it worked immediately.

```
{
    "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
    "name": "nestedTemplate",
    "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
    "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('siteName'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/certificates', variables('certificateName'))]"
    ],
    "properties": {
         "mode": "Incremental",
         "template": {
             "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
             "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
             "resources": [{
                 "apiVersion": "2019-08-01",
                 "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/hostnameBindings",
                 "name": "[variables('hostNameBindingsName')]",
                 "location": "[resourceGroup().location)]",
                 "properties": {
                      "sslState": "SniEnabled",
                      "thumbprint": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/certificates', variables('certificateName'))).Thumbprint]"
                  }
             }]
         }
     }
}
```